# CouchDB not Working on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, couchdb

I am making an Android app which uses couchDB for database storage.I am able to run the app on real device,but when I run the app on emulator it force closes with error messages as:-

```
    04-23 10:37:12.810: D/dalvikvm(319): VFY: dead code 0x0005-0036 in Lcom/couchbase/lite/storage/SQLiteStorageEngineFactory;.createStorageEngine ()Lcom/couchbase/lite/storage/SQLiteStorageEngine;
   04-23 10:37:12.820: D/AndroidRuntime(319): Shutting down VM
   04-23 10:37:12.820: W/dalvikvm(319): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (gro  up=0x4001d800)
  04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  java.util.ServiceLoader
    0 4-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at    com.couchbase.lite.storage.SQLiteStorageEngineFactory.createStorageEngine(SQLiteStorageEngineFactory.java:25)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at com.couchbase.lite.Database.open(Database.java:813)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at com.couchbase.lite.Manager.getDatabase(Manager.java:206)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at com.example.db.TestDB.startCBLite(TestDB.java:65)
   04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):   at com.example.db.TestDB.onCreate(TestDB.java:47)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):  at   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):    at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 04-23 10:37:12.840: E/AndroidRuntime(319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am new in couch db.Can anyone Please help me to run the app on Android Emulator..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html ... `Added in API level 9`

Answer (score 0):

It was posted as a comment, but yeah, the answer is that [ServiceLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) was added in Gingerbread (API level 9).  Try on a newer Android device/emulator.